# Cross site ads should show tags

Tags: bug, design, community-promotion-ads

Here's a cross site question ad I just saw on UX:

[image]

What game is this question is about? (Okay no fair if you've played Diablo 3). Arqade is probably one of the sites that benefits the most from showing the tag with the question, but the ads lack it; they also don't show how many answers there are.

Here's a Beta site ad, these show the tags and how many answers:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't the lack of tags actually make the ads more... interesting? :P

Comment: @badp I think *all* cross site ads should use a non-descript theme, to maximise confusion/curiosity.

Comment: Perhaps we should add random truncation like "Is it feasible to ..." and "Which way is better for ...". It's like a cliffhanger in TV series, you just want to click to see what the actual question is.